# UITabBarContoller, disappears last item from time to time

Tags: ios, swift

I have my custom `TabBarController` as usual, which contains 8 `viewController`.

```
class STTabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

let tabBarOrderKey = "tabBarOrderKey"
private var messangerNavigationController: UINavigationController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    configureViewControllers()
    setUpTabBarItemTags()
    getSavedTabBarItemsOrder()
}

func configureViewControllers() { 
    let clientsController = STClientsViewController(nibName: "STClientsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let clientNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: clientsController)
    clientsController.title = "Clients"
    clientNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Client")

    let openHouseController = STOpenHouseViewController(nibName: "STOpenHouseViewController", bundle: nil)
    let openHouseNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: openHouseController)
    openHouseController.title = "Open House"
    openHouseNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "OpenHouse")

    let performanceController = STChartsViewController(nibName: "STChartsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let performanceNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: performanceController)
    performanceController.title = "Performance"
    performanceNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Performance")

    let calculatorsController =  STCalculatorsViewController(nibName: "STCalculatorsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let calculatorsNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: calculatorsController)
    calculatorsController.title = "Calculators"
    calculatorsNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Calculators")
    let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let communityViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Navigation")
    communityViewController.title = "Community"
    communityViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage (named:"Community")
    let industryProfessionalsController = STIndustryProfessionalsViewController(nibName: "STIndustryProfessionalsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let industryProfessionalsNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: industryProfessionalsController)
    industryProfessionalsController.title = "Vendors"
    industryProfessionalsNavigationController.title = "Vendors"
    industryProfessionalsNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Industry-professionals")

    let agentResourcesController = STAgentResourcesViewController(nibName: "STAgentResourcesViewController", bundle: nil)
    let agentResourcesNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: agentResourcesController)
     agentResourcesController.title = "Resources"
    agentResourcesNavigationController.title = "Resources"
    agentResourcesNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Agent-Resources")


    let settingsController = STSettingsViewController(nibName: "STSettingsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let settingsNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: settingsController)
    settingsController.title = "Settings"
    settingsNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Settings")

    let coachController = STCoachsCornerViewController(nibName: "STCoachsCornerViewController", bundle: nil)
    let coachNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: coachController)
    coachController.navigationItem.title = "Action Plan"
    coachNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "Plan"
    coachNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Plan")

    self.viewControllers = [clientNavigationController ,performanceNavigationController,calculatorsNavigationController, coachNavigationController,industryProfessionalsNavigationController,agentResourcesNavigationController,openHouseNavigationController, settingsNavigationController]

    tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    let topBorder = CALayer()
    topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 0.5)
    topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.returnRGBColor(r: 229, g: 231, b: 235, alpha: 1).cgColor
    tabBar.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
    tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
}

func setUpTabBarItemTags() {
    var tag = 0
    if let viewControllers = viewControllers {
        for view in viewControllers {
            view.tabBarItem.tag = tag
            tag += 1
        }
    }
}

func getSavedTabBarItemsOrder() {
    var newViewControllerOrder = [UIViewController]()
    if let initialViewControllers = viewControllers {
        if let tabBarOrder = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: tabBarOrderKey) as? [Int] {
            for tag in tabBarOrder {
                newViewControllerOrder.append(initialViewControllers[tag])
            }
            setViewControllers(newViewControllerOrder, animated: false)
        }
    }
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didEndCustomizing viewControllers: [UIViewController], changed: Bool) {
    var orderedTagItems = [Int]()
    if changed {
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            let tag = viewController.tabBarItem.tag
            orderedTagItems.append(tag)

        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(orderedTagItems, forKey: tabBarOrderKey)
    }
}
```

And I met the problem when I start my on different devices and from time to time it can hide Settings(last) item in "More" tab.This look kinda ridiculous because code is straightforward and simple as you see and I dont know what can be wrong here. 
Does smb know what can it be? Thanks

Comment: Which IOS Simulator is this happening on? Try switching between simulators

Comment: @KingCoder11, Test Flight :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in saving order of this tabs to User Defaults.
I had 7 controllers, but when was trying to save it, saved was only 6.
Here is final code of saving function:

```
func getSavedTabBarItemsOrder() {
    var newViewControllerOrder = [UIViewController]()
    if let initialViewControllers = viewControllers {
        if let tabBarOrder = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: tabBarOrderKey) as? [Int] {
            for tag in tabBarOrder {
                newViewControllerOrder.append(initialViewControllers[tag])
            }
            let difference = Set(initialViewControllers).subtracting(newViewControllerOrder)
            newViewControllerOrder.append(contentsOf: difference)
            setViewControllers(newViewControllerOrder, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```